# Retrieve max decreased order values with its corresponding column names per each row

Tags: r

For the below dataframe input:

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(19,2,3,22), B = c(1,20,12,15) , C = c(10,11,19,0), D = c(0,13,8,2), E = c(75,21,4,80) )

   A  B  C  D  E
1 19  1 10  0 75
2  2 20 11 13 21
3  3 12 19  8  4
4 22 15  0  2 80
```

My current code retrieve the first three maximum output per line row as below:

```
t(apply(data, 1, function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA), 3)))

        [,1] [,2] [,3]

    [1,]   75   19   10
    [2,]   21   20   13
    [3,]   19   12    8
    [4,]   80   22   15
```

Well as I need the below output to retrieve the name tag with each max value saved in column beside the correspondent “max_value” N:

```
    [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]  [,6] 
[1,]   75   E   19   A    10       C
[2,]   21   E   20   B    13       D
[3,]   19   C   12   B    8        D
[4,]   80   E   22   A    15       B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow your method, you can redo the `apply` function to also get the names, and then just bind the two in an alternating way, i.e.

```
m1 <- t(apply(a, 1, function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA), 3)))
m2 <- t(apply(a, 1, function(x) names(head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE, na.last = NA), 3))))

matrix(c(rbind(m1, m2)), nrow = nrow(data))
```

Which gives,

> ```
>     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
> [1,] "75" "E"  "19" "A"  "10" "C" 
> [2,] "21" "E"  "20" "B"  "13" "D" 
> [3,] "19" "C"  "12" "B"  "8"  "D" 
> [4,] "80" "E"  "22" "A"  "15" "B"
> ```

Comment: when there are repetition of similar statements/functions, we can use mapply/Map etc.. eg:

     `a=mapply(function(i)apply(data,1,function(x)i(head(sort(x,TRUE),3))),c(function(m)m,names))`
`matrix(t(a),ncol=6,byrow=T)` Will give us the same results as above

Comment: @Onyambu thank you for mentioning it. I am aware. I just did it like that to follow the OP structure/syntax. We can also avoid `apply(df, 1, ...)` (which is horrible on data frames) altogether which would be the ideal solution. I will update with a more vectorized alternative as soon as I have some time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using `mutate_all` and `map2`.

We build a matrix of indices then build our rows separately with `map2` to join them back in the end :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purr)
data %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% 
  map2(mutate_all(.,order,decreasing = TRUE),~ (.x %>% rbind(names(data)))[,.y] %>% c) %>% 
  bind_cols %>% head(3*2) %>% t 

#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# V1 "75" "E"  "19" "A"  "10" "C" 
# V2 "21" "E"  "20" "B"  "13" "D" 
# V3 "19" "C"  "12" "B"  "8"  "D" 
# V4 "80" "E"  "22" "A"  "15" "B"
```